# Can a Callable be scheduled with ExecutorService to run 20 times with 0.5second delay and "break early" if done?

Tags: java, asynchronous, executorservice, scheduledexecutorservice

```
ResponsePOJO response = new ResponsePOJO();

for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++) {
    response = processResponse(client.execute(get));
    if (response.getStatus().equalsIgnoreCase("completed")) {
        break;
    }
    else { 
        Thread.sleep(500);
    }
}

return response;
```

Is there a better way to do this with an ExecutorService?

I was trying to do that with

```
ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors
  .newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();

Future<String> resultFuture = executor.scheduleAtFixedRate(runnableTask, 1, 500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
```

However, there are a couple of issues with this.

1. I cannot return the result as soon as it is available.
2. I have no way of setting the number of times I want it to execute.

Was wondering if there is any better way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used `ScheduledExecutorService` but based on [this example](https://mkyong.com/java/java-scheduledexecutorservice-examples/) I came up with the following code. I guess it's probably not the best code, since it's a first effort. Nonetheless it gets the job done. Explanations after the code.

```java
import java.time.LocalTime;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.ScheduledFuture;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import java.util.concurrent.atomic.AtomicBoolean;

public class SchedTst {
    static volatile AtomicBoolean  completed;
    static int  count;
    static int  val;
    static Random  rand;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        rand = new Random();
        val = rand.nextInt(10);
        System.out.println("val = " + val);
        ScheduledExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
        Runnable command = () -> {
            System.out.printf("%2d. %s%n", (count + 1), LocalTime.now());
            if (++count > 20) {
                completed = new AtomicBoolean();
                System.out.println("FALSE");
            }
            else {
                int anInt = rand.nextInt(10);
                System.out.println("anInt = " + anInt);
                if (anInt == val) {
                    completed = new AtomicBoolean(true);
                    System.out.println("TRUE");
                }
            }
        };
        ScheduledFuture<?> sf = executor.scheduleWithFixedDelay(command, 5, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        while (completed == null) {
            // Do nothing.
        }
        sf.cancel(true);
        executor.shutdown();
        System.out.println(completed);
    }
}
```

Basically you want to try something, at most, twenty times. As soon as it succeeds you don't want to try anymore and if it doesn't succeed after 20 attempts you also don't want to try anymore. You also want to wait half a second between successive tries. Since I have no idea what the "something" is, I made something up. At each try I generate a new random integer between zero and ten and compare it to some predetermined value. If the numbers match then the "something" has succeeded.

I print details to the screen purely for debugging purposes. They print statements are not needed. You can safely remove them.

Comment: this is similar but not quite the same. I want the Runnable to run 20 times - total. And

Comment: @DonCode do you mean that you want it to **always** run 20 times?

Comment: I want to run it 20 times max. But if I get the response I want early than I want to stop. @abra

Comment: @DonCode isn't that what I wrote in my answer? _As soon as it succeeds you don't want to try anymore and if it doesn't succeed after 20 attempts you also don't want to try anymore_